# about progress bar in jquery

Tags: jquery

ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js for progress bar.. but it is only displaying in orange color.. how to change the different themes.. did i need any another plugin..if any one have any link plz send me

thankyou

Comment: can you please post a link to the page where you are using this?

Comment: @Tarun.. no tarun.. it is in my system only.. so i cant send a link to u.. if u need i can send the code but it is too large..other wise give me your mail id i wl post to u...

Comment: temporarily upload on your test server and show it...

Comment: if you dont have a test server then simply go to some hosting site, signup there, get a ftp account, upload and share link... Its easier to solve a problem when you can see it in firebug

Comment: @Tarun...really!  i am not familiar with that.. i wl try.. but i am not sure that i may do now.. maaf karo yaar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When downloading the files, select a different theme (right hand side)

> http://jqueryui.com/download

You can check the different theme options here

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

I hope that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `background` property

```
.ui-widget-header { 
      background: #c02123 url(images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_75_c02123_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
}
```

or look at the actual progress bar class

```
.ui-progressbar-value { background: #c02123 !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the installation, 
Go to

```
CSS -> [Theme Name] -> Images
```

search for file named `"ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png"`
this is the file containing the orange color progress bar.

Open it in photoshop, use hue/saturation to change the color and save.

done!